# Is Yuri Bezmenov still alive?

Tags: politics, espionage

[Yuri Bezmenov](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yuri_Bezmenov), was a former [KGB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KGB) agent who defected to the USA, and is well known for his claims that the KGB was/is involved in an attempt to "brainwash" the USA through [ideological subversion](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5It1zarINv0).

Wikipedia references a Windsor Public Library obituary listing dated January 7, 1993; however, I cannot find any sources that back up this claim, and I cannot find sources that document the circumstances surrounding his death.  I am thus skeptical of this claim that Yuri died in 1993, and I have heard from some that he may still be alive.

Can someone please provide evidence that documents whether he indeed did die in 1993 at the age of 54, and from what cause?

Comment: Something strange i realized watching this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5It1zarINv0 What year was this shot? Looks like something from the late 70's/early 80s. That would make him 38-42 in this video considering his DOB of 1939. Maybe a fluke of bad genetics but he must be older.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, I have to agree that Wikipedia's source *Windor Public Library* isn't that convincing. The only thing that Windor Public Library provided was this [database entry](http://projects.windsorpubliclibrary.com/digi/obits/results.php?lname=Schuman&fname=Tomas%20D&maiden=&spouse=&m1=0&y1=0&m2=0&y2=0&lim=25&search=Search):
[image]

The best evidence which could be provided here is a Death Certificate, but it seems you won't find that easily online.

Many users have been skeptical about his death and they have expressed their thoughts [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Yuri_Bezmenov), [here](https://archive.4plebs.org/pol/thread/32405750/) and [here](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20111029211430AAkiA4H).

I found an [article](http://search.proquest.com/docview/254023823?accountid=8555) published on  06 Jan 1993, by The Windsor Star, a newspaper, which seems seem to be pretty reputable, it has been published on "**proquest.com**". It has an abstract, can be cited and used in research.

If you can't access the article (due to country restriction or sign up/login) I have exported it to my GDrive [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7dmym4cK6ABRU5lNlZpYVlGVEE/view?usp=sharing).

The article explicitly mentions that:

> The 52-year-old Russian propaganda expert - who recently taught at the
>   University of Windsor - **died Tuesday at Grace Hospital of a massive
>   heart attack following a life-long fight with alcoholism**.

The article ended without mentioning an exact date of death:

> **Mr. Schuman moved to Windsor following his divorce in 1989** and began
>   teaching public relations at the University of Windsor two years
>   later.
>
> Just before Christmas, he was in Montreal for a brief visit with his
>   ex-wife Tess and their two children, 14-year-old Tanya and 10-year-old
>   Jonathan.
>
> **He died two weeks later.** The funeral is scheduled for Friday.

But we can estimate: So, 1989 + 2 years == 1991 or 1992 which seem pretty close to the time of death date by Window Public Library: Jan 7, 1993.

So, is that enough to prove that he died? Not necessarily, you have to remain skeptical;  even if I provide you with a death certificate, it is well known that the guy has been a KBG spy with a fake name, which makes a faked death possible.

Comment: It sounds like he moved to Windsor in 1989, began teaching in about 1991, and died a year or two after that (after "recently teaching"). Per the article you found, he was in Montreal for Christmas and died two weeks later, which squares with the obituary being published January 7th.

Comment: This is a good answer backed by references. Why are you afraid it might be deleted.